# Python: Package directory does not exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, setup.py

I'm trying to install a python package in windows 10 using the following setup.py file.

```
"""Setup file for uhd module"""

from setuptools import setup

setup(name='uhd',
      version='3.14.0',
      description='Universal Software Radio Peripheral (USRP) Hardware Driver Python API',
      classifiers=[
          'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
          'License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)',
          'Programming Language :: C++',
          'Programming Language :: Python',
          'Topic :: System :: Hardware :: Hardware Drivers',
      ],
      keywords='SDR UHD USRP',
      author='Ettus Research',
      author_email='packages@ettus.com',
      url='https://www.ettus.com/',
      license='GPLv3',
      package_dir={'': 'C:/Users/bcollins/UHD_PY/uhd/host/build/python'}, 
      package_data={'uhd': ['*.so']},
      zip_safe=False,
      packages=['uhd'],
      install_requires=['numpy'])
```

I execute the script using the command

```
python setup.py install
```

I do this from the directory that contains the setup.py file.

This returns the following error

```
error: package directory 'C:Users\bcollins\UHD_PY\uhd\host\build\python\uhd' does not exist
```

There is a folder called "uhd" at that location though. The folder contains the `__init__.py` file

If the script isn't looking for this folder, what is it looking for?

I'm not exactly experienced in this area but my best guess is that its looking for a .so file within the "uhd" folder at that location, but I'm not sure.

I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`package_dir` has to be a relative path, not an absolute path. The distutils layer under setuptools [tries](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/distutils/util.py#L109) to reject absolute paths, but the `C:` confuses it. It ends up converting your path to

```
C:Users\bcollins\UHD_PY\uhd\host\build\python\uhd
```

Note the missing backslash between `C:` and `Users`. This path is relative to your current working directory on the C drive ([windows drive handling is weird](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats)), and relative to your working directory, this path is invalid.

Comment: Yup, that did it. I just commented out the `package_dir` line and it ran. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 22):

This doesn't answer the original question, but it's how I fixed the same error.

I had:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages('src', exclude=['test']),
    ...
)
```

I had added the `src` argument because my packages are located in `src`, but it turns out [`find_packages`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html) is smart enough on it's own.

Remove the first argument:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['test']),
    ...
)
```

This was on Python 3.5, but I imagine it applies to most other versions.

Comment: Not sure why it works, but it does! Thanks

Comment: And I'm not sure why is there a "where" directive in the first place, if it's not really needed. I spent like 40 minutes debugging this, because I specifically added "src"(where="src").
Without it the errors are gone. But the package comes out empty.
I've solved the issue by using `pyproject.toml` instead of `setup.py` config.
Detailed the solution in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, it turned out that you just need to add a slash after your package directory:  `packages=['uhd']` should be `packages=['uhd/']`.

Comment: Thank you! same works if you're using setup.cfg
```
[options]
packages =
    uhd/
    uhd.subp
```

Answer (score 1):

For me *kelloti*'s answer removed the error. But the package was still not being built right. It would get built empty.
I solved this by using `pyproject.toml` instead of `setup.py` format of the config file.
Somehow, the options presented [in the setuptools docs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#package-discovery) for setup.py:

```
packages=find_packages(
    where='src',
    include=['mypackage'],
),
```

Just don't work right. They either produce an empty package, or a package named "src", with my actual package inside of it.

Using the exact same options but in `pyproject.toml` config file works properly:

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
include = ["mypackage*"]
```

And I am no longer having errors when building, while my package is installed properly(rather than being installed under `src` directory)

Answer (score 1):

To react to @MickeyDickey's comment, you can still successfully build your package with `setup.py` even if you use a *src-layout*. You just have to provide this: `package_dir = {"": "src"}` to the `setup` function. See [setuptools documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html) for more information.

Ending with something like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages('src', exclude=['test']),
    package_dir = {"": "src"},
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this error can occur when in the python scripts folder (%python_root%\scripts) is not in the environment PATH.